# Initializing a class object that uses dependency injection

Tags: java, object, dependency-injection, guice

I am working on creating a JAVA library that does no use any dependency injection framework. I need to use a class from an external library. The external library uses DI framework to inject dependency.
Now I need to use a particular class let's call it A. A uses two object in its constructor. So to initialise A in my code I can do

`A aObject = new A(xObject, yObject);`

But the problem is that X and Y classes intern need other dependency to initialise them. So I'm kinda stuck in a rabit-hole where I keep on initializing deeper object. Is there a way I can initialize A without using any DI framework in my library?

Comment: Try to design your libraries according to [these guidelines](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/).

Answer (score 0):

This hradly depends on the library you are using. Your only option is to make the library instantiate the class by itself using it's DI. Unfortunately we cannot help you without more information on the library.